# Is it possible to set a static IP for each WiFi connection?

Tags: static-ip

Say wifi1 is on 192.168.1.1 and wifi2 is on 10.11.11.1, I think I need a separate static IP for each network e.g. 192.168.1.233 won’t work on wifi2. Is there a way the raspberry pi can automatically switches between IP’s based on which WiFi it's connected to?

Comment: The normal way of switching IP based on network is DHCP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dhcpcd` can configure interfaces dependent on the host network. This uses the Address Resolution Protocol (ARP) to probe hosts based on MAC or IP address before attempting DHCP resolution.

See **Host Specific Configuration** in [How to set up networking/WiFi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697)

Comment: It's also possible to use the SSID to set IP, etc

Answer (score 0):

go to dhcpcd.conf and edit IP address as per each wifi requirement and enable ARPing.

Try this way:

```
interface eth0
arping 192.168.2.1
arping 192.168.4.50
profile 192.168.2.1
static ip_address =192.168.2.44/24
static routers=192.168.2.1
static domain_name_servers=192.168.2.1

profile 192.168.4.50
static ip_address=192.168.0.44/24
static routers=192.168.4.50
static domain_name_servers=192.168.4.50
```

Refer https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=66&t=140252

Comment: It would be helpful if you would give more details on how exactly this should / could be done.